# Docker containers safe upgrade best practice

Tags: docker, docker-compose, upgrade, restore, backup-strategies

I manage several applications running under docker (Nexus, Gitlab, and so on), with its own storage mapped to host disks.

Often they get updated, so I have to upgrade them.

Sometimes they introduce breaking changes which prevent the containers to restart (for example Gitlab 16 is no more compatible with docker 19 or below).

I designed a backup/restore policy in order engage a disaster recover process in such situations.

I would ask if there exist a best (standard) pratice to achieve the same goal.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: How exactly are you currently updating your applications?

Comment: Currently I stop the container, I do a tar/gz of the external storages, I edit the docker file to point to the newer release, then I restart it. In case of failure (which may have changed external files), I restore the external storage, I revert the docker file, and I restart the old container version. I would know if there is a tool or a best pratice to do it better and more safely.